# How to set sleep into the flow in Mulesoft without losing the message payload

Tags: java, groovy, mule, mule-component

I'd like insert script to delay processing flow in Mulesoft. I have tried to insert script in groovy but I lost the messagge payload, so when I have to get message payload recived null pointer.
How can I to do not lose the message payload?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? Your flow including the groovy script?

Comment: I put the component "Script", in the flow, and into window to the section General-->Script Text, I put sleep(10000)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using **Groovy** component in you flow,then you can define sleep() as follow :-

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
  <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
    sleep(10000);
    return message.payload;]]>
  </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

And **remember** **to** **return** message.payload in **Groovy** so that you can get the **payload** at the end or else you will get **null** payload

**Groovy** has an issue of loosing payload if you don't return at the end, so, in **Groovy** you need to return the payload at end, and that's the reason you are receiving **null** payload

Alternately you can use **expression-component** as follow:-

```
<expression-component>
    Thread.sleep(10000);
</expression-component>
```

Comment: This method works, although there should be a warning about the runtime deployment. While sleeping the application seems to be reluctant about undeploying itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can call Thread.sleep from a Java component, a MEL component or even a Groovy component.

However, this is tipically a design flaw unless you are testing something. If this is for production (and a delay is realy-realy-realy needed) consider other solutions like delayed messages using JMS.

Answer (score 2):

In Mule 4 you should use the Runtime "wait" function. Any other alternative will block all your threads. 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-runtime-functions-wait

Comment: Hey where did you see in the docs that it wont block all the threads?

Answer (score -1):

You can use groovy code like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:http=http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http     
 xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" 
 xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
 xmlns:doc=http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation 
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting 
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
  <flow name="groovyFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/groovy" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
      <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
        <![CDATA[sleep(10000);
         System.out.println("Holding for 10 seconds");
         return message.payload;]]></scripting:script>
      </scripting:transformer>
  </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use groovy code here, like below you can.

```
def name = sessionVars.username;         
def a = sessionVars.int1.toInteger()+1;        
def b = sessionVars.int2.toInteger();          
def c = a+b;      
sessionVars.sum = c;      
sessionVars.int1 = a;      
if(name != null){       
name = name           
}           
else{            
name = '';            
}      
sleep(3000);        
System.out.println("Holding the flow for 3000 ms");
```

Answer (score -3):

You can make use of Groovy component to add delay.

```
sleep(20000)
```