# Mule - Start/ Stop flow from command line/ mule server

Tags: mule, mule-component

Can anyone please suggest how can we start and stop a Mule flow from the mule server using commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the bin folder in the mule server.

Start: ./mule start 
Stop: ./mule stop 
Status: ./mule status

Comment: Thanks for your response! These commands are for starting/ stopping Mule server. I need the commands for starting/ stopping Mule flow in a mule application.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the anchor file undeploys the application.

For Reference :
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/application-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, you can only stop a flow via mmc.

Comment: Thanks Alex for taking a look! Could you please let me know if Mule documentation says anywhere that we cannot start/ stop a mule flow from command line?

Comment: Hi, It is not explicitly written in the documentation that you cannot do it. However, what you can do with the command line is written [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb). Hope it helps. /T

Comment: In addition, you have the Mule Agent API available [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-agent/v/1.4.0/) but it seems that there is no resource for starting/stopping flows. /T

Comment: Thank you!! I will look through the documentation, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop individual flow of mule application.If you would like to stop the complete mule application from running .

1. If you are using mmc --> you can find stop button over there to stop running.
2. If you  are using command prmt deployment remove the specific anchor.txt file for the mule application under apps folder and rerun the mule.bat file to restart the server.
3. If you are deploying via cloudhub, you can find undeploy button in settings page of the application of Runtime manager you can just click on that.

Thanks,
Lakshmi.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold or freeze the message for a certain time in a flow though with Groovy scripting and build logic around it achieve something similar to start/stop. Hope it helps.

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
     sleep(10000);
     return message.payload;]]>
    </scripting:script>
     </scripting:component>
```

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115684/how-to-set-sleep-into-the-flow-in-mulesoft-without-losing-the-message-payload